# Parallel queries for a single connection in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I found the documentation about parallel queries and parallel sequential scans that PostgreSQL 9.6 does, but I couldn't find anything about if PostgreSQL 9.6 can, on a **single** connection run multiple queries concurrently(I know I can open multiple connections and run the queries simultaneously).

Say I have 2 queries I want to execute(on a single connection):

`SELECT * FROM table1;`

 `SELECT * FROM table2;`

Is there any way on PostgreSQL server-side for these queries to run concurrently?

Sources would be appreciated.

Comment: A single connection (session) can only execute a single statement at one given time. If you want to run two different queries in parallel, you need two connections (this is no different in any other DBMS)

Comment: Parallel sequential scans sounds like a technique the DBMS uses to optimize a single query not a feature a feature available to application developers.  If you link to the documentation where you found this we may be able to give more of an insight.

Comment: @PhilipCouling My bad in saying PostgreSQL offers these. I meant that the DBMS uses those techniques to optimize a single query. [Here is the link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/parallel-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `pg_send_query` and `pg_get_result` you can execute multiple queries asynchronously in `PHP` like so:

```
<?php
  $dbconn = pg_connect("dbname=publisher") or die("Could not connect");

  if (!pg_connection_busy($dbconn)) {
      pg_send_query($dbconn, "select * from authors; select count(*) from authors;");
  }

  $res1 = pg_get_result($dbconn);
  echo "First call to pg_get_result(): $res1\n";
  $rows1 = pg_num_rows($res1);
  echo "$res1 has $rows1 records\n\n";

  $res2 = pg_get_result($dbconn);
  echo "Second call to pg_get_result(): $res2\n";
  $rows2 = pg_num_rows($res2);
  echo "$res2 has $rows2 records\n";
?>
```

For more info, you can refer to [official page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-send-query.php)

Hope it'd helped you

Comment: Unless PHP silently creates two distinct physical connections for that, the queries will still not run in parallel. The Postgres backend simply doesn't support that, a single connection can only run one statement at a time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, I thought so. But I searched through the web and I found that. Do you say that the PHP manual is misleading about this or something?